# How to connect React.js/React Native Apps to one single backend instance of Azure App Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, reactjs, react-native

I'm planning to create 1) react.js web app 2) react Native android/ios apps, and I want to create one unified node.js backend to serve as a single API for both web and mobile apps.

I would also like to take advantage of Azure's notifications hub and authentication. For authentication, I'll also need to have custom username/pw rather than just social accounts. What should I do? Can AAD achieve it?

I realized whilst Azure has great support for native iOS/Android Apps, it's not entirely clear on whether it supports React/React Native Apps as well.

To what extent would the javascript mobile App SDK help?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide single APIs for both web clients and devices, and implement Notification push, you can use [Azure Mobile Apps in Node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/).

> For authentication, I'll also need to have custom username/pw rather than just social accounts. What should I do? Can AAD achieve it?

If you want to custom authentication on your Mobile Apps, you can refer to https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/ for details. And to use AAD, you only can authentication your users in your tenant in AD. (the user name is inthe format:`<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com`).

At last, as React/React Native Apps are based on javascript, so you are right, you can implement the Mobile Apps functionalities with [JavaScript Client Library for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/)

Here is a [post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/03/22/integrating-auth0-with-azure-mobile-apps-javascript-client/) in the similar scenario with you, maybe it will help you.